# Oracle Identifying multiple spaces using REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to identify fields that have more than one space in a comment, e.g. `'this    lhas   three   spaces'`

Using this I can get anything with two spaces, but would like to be able to get 2 or more:

```
select * from labtec.spaces
where REGEXP_LIKE(SPACES, '[[:space:]]{2}');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can:

```
select * from labtec.spaces
where REGEXP_LIKE(SPACES, '[[:space:]]{2,}');
```

Note the comma.

For "Between three and five" you would use `{3,5}`, for "two or more" `{2,}`, for "eight or less" `{,8}`

Comment: Excellent, that worked a treat.  One more thing though, can I also include trailing and leading spaces in using '(^ | $)'

Comment: Sure, I think you would `(^ | $|[[:space:]]{2,})`. You'd want to be clear about whether you wanted to be using `[[:space:]]` or ` ` throughout I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to check for two-or-more characters - checking for two is sufficient to filter the rows since if there are three characters then matching only two of them will work just as well as matching two-or-more.

This will find strings which have two or more (consecutive or non-consecutive) space `CHR(32)` characters (without using regular expressions):

```
SELECT *
FROM   labtec.spaces
WHERE  INSTR( spaces, ' ', 1, 2 ) > 0
```

This will find where there are two or more consecutive space `CHR(32)` characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM   labtec.spaces
WHERE  INSTR( spaces, '  ' ) > 0
```

If you want any two (or more) consecutive white-space characters then you only need to check for two matching characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM   labtec.spaces
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( spaces, '\s\s' ) -- Or, using POSIX syntax '[[:space:]]{2}'
```

**Update - Leading and trailing spaces**

```
SELECT *
FROM   labtec.spaces
WHERE  SUBSTR( spaces, 1, 2 ) = '  ' -- at least two leading spaces
OR     SUBSTR( spaces, -2 )   = '  ' -- at least two trailing spaces
```

or, using (perl-like) regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   labtec.spaces
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( spaces, '^\s\s|\s\s$' )
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can I also include a test for leading and trailing spaces in the same REGEXP_LIKE expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(SPACES, '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+');
```